# C++ Class that contains two functions. Allocating memory in main

Tags: c++, class, memory, dynamic, c++14

so I'm trying to solve the following task:

[image: Task]

Below is the code that I've come up with. I'm having trouble storing the data correctly and I'm not sure where to put the read() and output() function. This probably isn't all too difficult but I'm still not sure. Can somebody maybe give me a hint? Thank you!

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    string name, department;
    int age;

    void output(string &a, int &b, string &c)
    {
        cout << name << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << age << " years" << endl;
        cout << "Department: " << department << endl;
    }

    void read(int &n)
    {
            cout << "Enter number, last name and first name:";
            cin >> name;

            cout << "Enter age:";
            cin >> age;

            cout << "Enter department:";
            cin >> department;
        }
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of employees: ";
    cin >> n;
    Employee* o = new Employee;
    Employee employee;



   delete o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without running your code, it looks pretty close to a working solution
You are keeping the data in the fields of the instance of your Employee class

which you are storing somewhere on the heap. And accessing with the pointer o

some suggestions:

There is no need to pass anything into the read function, it is reading in one employees details per call.

If you want to create multiple employees then you would want to create vector to hold them in, then a for loop that runs n times and inside that for loop create a new employee call their read and output functions and add them to the vector (otherwise you will loose your pointers and have a memory leak).

Use o->read()  to dereference your pointer and call its read function.

The fields of your employee are best made private member variables.
I.E name,department, age.
This will still compile and run but it is better design to make things private unless they have a need to be public.

In addition I do  not think you need the last line, you have already created a new employee and a pointer to it in the line above.

lastly when you go to delete just iterate through your vector of employees and delete each one.

Short on time in this moment, but I will try to circle back and add some code examples later if you need em.